# Write top k values of RDD to a file in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I want to extract top k values from an RDD of Tuple2 objects and write them to a file.
The way I had been trying is to use the top function and pass it a Comparator object. This returns a list of Tuple2 objects.

Now I can coalesce this list on a single node and iterate over this list and print the values to a file using FileWriter.
But that will result in a single file. And I would prefer to have several files for each reducer.

Is there any way I can use saveAsTextFile on a List rather than on an RDD?
I'm using Spark 1.5.1 with Java.

```
Comparator<Tuple2<String, Double>> tc = new TupleComparator();

    List<Tuple2<String,Double>> output = ranks.coalesce(1,true).top(topK,tc);

  /*  for (Tuple2<String,Double> tuple : output){
        System.out.println(tuple._1() + " has rank: " + tuple._2() + ".");
    }*/
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[2],false));
    int i=1;
    for(Tuple2<String,Double> tuple: output) {
      writer.write(i + " " + tuple._1 + " " + tuple._2);
      writer.newLine();
      i++;
    }
    writer.close();
```

Comment: You should start with [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreachPartition`, and use FileWriter (or PrintWriter in my code sample) on each partition, like so:

```
import scala.util.Random

sc.parallelize( {1 to 12}.zipWithIndex, 4)
      .foreachPartition( part => 
            printToFile(new File(s"partition_${Random.nextInt}"))  
            {p=> part.foreach(p.println)}
       )
```

where I use the following to output a list :

```
import java.io._

  //  usage:  printToFile(new File("filename")) { p => myCollection.foreach(p.println) }

def printToFile(f: java.io.File)(op: java.io.PrintWriter => Unit) { 
        val p = new java.io.PrintWriter(f); 
        try { op(p) } finally { p.close() } 
}
```